# Is there a way I can remove the need to have an App.Xaml and add resources to App.Xaml.cs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to move this to my App.Xaml.cs. Can someone give me some suggestion how I can do this?

```
<Application
    x:Class="Test.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Test">
    <Application.Resources>
        <converters:InverseBool x:Key="InverseBool" />
        <converters:ToUpper x:Key="ToUpper" />
        <converters:BoolToStringStateConverter x:Key="BoolToStringStateConverter" />
        <converters:AddHashToNumberConverter x:Key="AddHashToNumberConverter" />
        <converters:BoolToIntRowSpanConverter x:Key="BoolToIntRowSpanConverter" />
        <converters:StringToTextAligmentConverter x:Key="StringToTextAligmentConverter" />
        <converters:BoolToStringTextConverter x:Key="BoolToStringTextConverter" />
        <converters:BoolToStringTextForDeckSourcesConverter x:Key="BoolToStringTextForDeckSourcesConverter" />
        <converters:EpochSecondsToDateStringConverter x:Key="EpochSecondsToDateStringConverter" />
        <converters:IntervalToDaysConverter x:Key="IntervalToDaysConverter" />
        <converters:BoolToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BoolToBackgroundColorConverter" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Is there a way that I can add this to App.xaml.cs instead of having this in a XAML file?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98052/add-global-resources-programmatically

Comment: Hi, sorry  for not understanding why need to move code from `Xaml` to `.cs`. Somethimes we not need to add them in `Application.Resources`, just add them in which Xaml need to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the steps to delete `App.xaml`, replace it with `App.cs` and add your converter resources to `Application.Resources`.

The resource dictionary, `Application.Resources`, is just a `Dictionary<string, object>` into which we can pass any key-value pair. So we'll pass in each `IValueConverter` using the name of the class and an instance of the class, e.g. `Application.Current.Resources.Add(nameof(InverseBool), new InverseBool());`

#### 1. Delete `App.xaml`

1. In the Solution Explorer, right click on `App.xaml`
2. In the right-click drop-down menu, click **Delete**

[image]

#### 2. Add `App.cs`

1. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the .NET Standard Project containing your Xamarin.Forms UI
2. In the right-click drop-down menu, select **Add** > **New File**

[image]

3. In the **New File** window, on the left-hand pane, select **General**
4. In the **New File** window, in the center pane, select **Empty Class**
5. In the **New File** window, in the bottom **Name** text box, enter **App**
6. In the **New File** window, click **New**

[image]

#### 3. Add Resources to App.cs

1. In the Solution Explorer, open `App.cs`
2. In **App.cs**, add your converter resources by entering the following code:

```cs
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Resources.Add(nameof(InverseBool), new InverseBool());
        Resources.Add(nameof(ToUpper), new ToUpper());
        Resources.Add(nameof(BoolToStringStateConverter), new BoolToStringStateConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(AddHashToNumberConverter), new AddHashToNumberConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(BoolToIntRowSpanConverter), new BoolToIntRowSpanConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(StringToTextAligmentConverter), new StringToTextAligmentConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(BoolToStringTextConverter), new BoolToStringTextConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(BoolToStringTextForDeckSourcesConverter), new BoolToStringTextForDeckSourcesConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(EpochSecondsToDateStringConverter), new EpochSecondsToDateStringConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(IntervalToDaysConverter), new IntervalToDaysConverter());
        Resources.Add(nameof(BoolToBackgroundColorConverter), new BoolToBackgroundColorConverter());

        MainPage = ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to keep `App.xaml` clean, you can use [the merged dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merged-resource-dictionaries) (and this is a best practice) and split all your resources into its own dictionary file, then use the merged dictionary to combine them in `App.xaml`.

If the goal is to define resources in .cs instead of .xaml, then you can access that dictionary right from the `App.cs` via `this.Resources` dictionary.

Comment: My goal is to completely remove the .xaml.  I'm hoping someone can show me how to do this.